# How can I display in rails "only" hours and seconds using simple_form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, simple-form-for

I am quite new in rails but I could not find an answer for this.

I have the column `start` defined as `datetime` type. However, when displaying the form in the view, I want only to see the hours and seconds (and hide the year, month and day) fields.

```
<%= simple_form_for @availability do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :start %>
   <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary wide-btn" %>
<% end %>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I assume you mean the user enters only "hours, minutes, and seconds".  If the user enters "08:04:05", what do you want the value to be?  If you really only want the time, you should define the `start` attribute as a `time`, not a `datetime`.

Comment: `f.input :start, as: :time`?

Comment: However @JohnFeltz is correct. If you set a date from a time input the day will be very ambiguous and you will have to override how rails handles the params from date inputs. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#using-date-and-time-form-helpers

Comment: On a side note - `simple_form` is great. But if you are building an app to learn rails then use the bare bones rails form helpers as `simple_form` abstracts away a lot of valuable lessons.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your datatype from `datetime` to `time`. simple_form has a time selector helper. https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#available-input-types-and-defaults-for-each-column-type